# Facebook Graph API check likes

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

How do I check if the authenticated user has liked a particular post?

I am not using the Facebook SDK.

Thanks!

Comment: may i ask what you need this for?

Comment: because, just so you know, like gating and rewarding a user for a like is not allowed according to the platform policy of facebook.

Comment: nothing of the sort. just a simple like/unlike functionality

Comment: @lunschn I doesn't find any information about rewarding, can you plz share link with this rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Facebook Graph API*, there is fields *likes*, so it will get all likes data of the specific post. Then, you can check whether your friend id in the likes data.
[image]

With a post has lot of likes, you can use limit parameter like this.

```
/{post_id}?fields=likes.limit(5000)
```

The likes data supports paging, so you might fetch all likes of the post.

Comment: Is there no other solution? It is very inefficient